# How to Change Loop to Order Posts by Views (using wp-postviews plugin)

Tags: loop, views

I hope somebody would be kind enough to help. I currently have a page that orders all of the posts by comment count, but I want to change the loop to order the posts by view count. I have installed the 'wp-postviews.1.50' plugin and have got it to display the number of views on each post, so I know that side of it is working, now I just need the loop code changed to order by most views, is this possible?

This is the how the number of views is called out:

```
<?php $views = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'views', true); ?><?php echo $views; ?>
```

And here is the loop I need changed:

```
<?php $posts_per_page = get_query_var('posts_per_page'); ?>
<?php $paged = intval(get_query_var('paged')); ?>
<?php $paged = ($paged) ? $paged : 1; ?>
<?php $args = array(
'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
'paged' => $paged,
'more' => $more = 0,
'orderby' => 'comment_count',
'order' => 'DESC',
); ?>
<?php query_posts($args); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post() ;?>
<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

I'm using WordPress 3.0.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just wanted to give an update. Someone was kind enough to show me how to update the code I posted above. It turned out to be quite simple (if you know what you're doing!). So I have posted it below for anyone that wants to do something similar.

```
<?php $posts_per_page = get_query_var('posts_per_page'); ?>
<?php $paged = intval(get_query_var('paged')); ?>
<?php $paged = ($paged) ? $paged : 1; ?>
<?php $args = array(
'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
'paged' => $paged,
'more' => $more = 0,
'meta_key' => 'views',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'DESC',
); ?>
<?php query_posts($args); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post() ;?>
<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou!

Answer (score 0):

From the plugin documentation

> To Display Most Viewed Posts Use:

```
<?php if
(function_exists('get_most_viewed')):
?>
<ul>
      <?php get_most_viewed(); ?>    
</ul> <?php endif; ?>
```

> The first value
>   you pass in is what you want to get,
>   'post', 'page' or 'both'. The second
>   value you pass in is the maximum
>   number of post you want to get.
>
> Default: get_most_viewed('both', 10);

Comment: Thanks for replying. I can see how to get a list of the posts, what I'm struggling with though is how to change the loop I've posted above to get the posts in order of most viewed.

Comment: You'll need to add a custom sorting to the order_by parameter then. Have a look at this: http://www.gab.ro/post-sorting-reloaded/ which is a plugin that 'wraps the posts_orderby filter' for some ideas. However, it looks like posts_orderby has been deprecated - so you might need to be careful there

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at that. I was hoping though that someone on here might have done something similar in the past and could show me exactly how my code above would need to be changed. Though from what you've said it doesn't sound like a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$args=array(
 'posts_per_page'      => 15, 
 'post_type'     => 'post', 
 'key' => 'views',
 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
 'order'    => 'ASC',
 'post_status' => 'publish'
);

query_posts($args); ?>
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made it this way pretty nicely :)

```
<?php $args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
  'category_name' => 'xyz',
  'meta_key' => 'views',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'post_status' => 'publish'
); ?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Explain why your code should work.