# wp custom field date format compare

Tags: custom-field, date-time

How do I possible to work with this code to work with date format Y-n-j

Value

```
start_date = 2011-1-20
end_date   = 2011-1-30
```

Here are the original function came from this [Query between two meta values?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6953/query-between-two-meta-values/7006)

```
function date_check_join( $join ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $join .= " JOIN ".$wpdb->postmeta." AS startdate ON 
        (".$wpdb->posts.".ID = startdate.post_id AND
        startdate.meta_key = 'start_date')
        JOIN ".$wpdb->postmeta." AS enddate ON 
        (".$wpdb->posts.".ID = enddate.post_id AND
        enddate.meta_key = 'end_date')";
    return $join;
    }

function date_check_where( $where ) {
    $today = date('Y-n-j'); /* I change this format to date('Y-n-j')*/
    $where .= " AND startdate.meta_value <= $today
    AND enddate.meta_value >= $today";
    return $where;
    }
```

This function is working with `UNIX TIME STAMP date('Ymd')` and when I change date format it doesn't work with `date('Y-n-j')`
credit @goldenapples

Comment: have you tried `strtotime` ?

Comment: @Crono Yes but nothing happen it doesn't return any data

Answer (score 2):

Hi **@idontknowhow:**

You've focused on trying to solve the problem in PHP when in fact you needed to focus on the SQL. Your first problem was you reversed the *"polarity" (which is a term I made up just now, but it kinda fits)*; you were looking for both a start date that was greater than today and an end date the was earlier than today; a logical impossibility.

Second problem ignoring the reversed polarity was more subtle; you were comparing dates with equal length strings so you could get a false positive. This SQL illustrates the problem:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE '2011-9-20' < '2011-11-20'
```

The `WHERE` criteria *"looks"* true and thus the query should return all records when in fact it returns none and that is because `'2011-9' < '2011-1'` is actually false.

So here's a working replacement for your `date_check_where()` function that uses the SQL `DATE()` function to normalize the strings in dates into real date values so they can be compared and it of course fixes the polarity issue I mentioned at first:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'date_check_where' );
function date_check_where( $where ) {
  $today = date('Y-m-d');
  $where .=<<<SQL
 AND DATE(startdate.meta_value) >= DATE('{$today}')
 AND DATE(enddate.meta_value) <= DATE('{$today}')
SQL;
  return $where;
}
```

Note I used `date('Y-m-d')` instead of `date('Y-n-j')` because I find it cleaner to use, and it doesn't need to make the meta fields because of the `DATE()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put values for comparison in quotes, those minuses might be getting it interpreted as mathematical expression instead of string:

```
$where .= " AND 'startdate.meta_value' <= '$today'
    AND 'enddate.meta_value' >= '$today'";
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work is there any solution for this.. .thanks