# Display movies that apear this day next

Tags: php, custom-field, customization

This code retrive me the movies that are comming in cinema, i want to be able to list movies that apear this day, next day ... 7 day week

Ex: Today is 13.05.2013, i want to list the  movies that apear this day (  - the code down list me all the movies that are comming)... and if the day pass to 14.05 i want the box post disapear from page.

The code down do that but it display all upcomming movies. 
I want to list only today movies

Something like this : http://tvpedia.org/program-tv

How can i do that?

Thanks in advance

```
 <?php // Get today's date in the right format
    $todaysDate = date('Ymd');
    ?>
    <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' =>3,
    'meta_key' => 'premiera_cinema',
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'meta_value' => $todaysDate,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
    ) ); ?>
    <?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: I bet the content of `meta_value` is not a date formatted with `Ymd`. Normally it is formatted with `Y-m-d`

Comment: the format is yymmdd

Comment: Problem solved?

Comment: this code up work's but i need to get only for all 7 days of week separate.

Comment: [This answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6953/query-between-two-meta-values) show you how.

Comment: ok thanks for that link but i do not have a end day, i only want to list movies that apear for yesterday( in a box), today(in a box), tomorrow,... 7 days ... like in that link up.

Comment: I have an start date, the date that movie apear in cinema, on that i want to be able to list movies by days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do in this case is to use a meta_query in WP_Query like the following. You can reference the following Codex for more information https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters. Once you have the posts. Loop over them and add their date as data attribute, and filter the items using data attributes.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'premiera_cinema',
            //Beginning and End date in format of YYYYMMDD
            'value'     => array( 20130101, 20130107 ),
            'type'      => 'date',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```