# query_posts() vs get_posts() multiple loops

Tags: loop, query-posts, get-posts

I have a template which initially had one single loop and it was using query_posts, I added 2 more loops using the same method, However after reading allot about these it was concluded that I shall stop using it and everyone is against using it.

**original query_posts loop (latest posts)**

```
<?php if ( !is_front_page() && tfuse_options(PREFIX.'_pagination_portfolio') ){
    $cat = get_query_var( 'cat' );
    query_posts( array ( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'cat'=>$cat ) );
}
while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    //blah posts here
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**2nd custom get_posts loop (random posts)**

```
<?php if ( !is_front_page() ){
    //$cat = get_query_var( 'cat' );
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
    $rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
}
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : ?>
    //blah posts here
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**3rd custom get_posts loop no working (most viewed posts)**

```
if ( !is_front_page() ){
    $cat = get_query_var( 'cat' );
    $args = array( 'v_sortby' => 'views', 'v_orderby' => 'DESC', 'numberposts' => 10, 'cat'=> $cat);
    $most_viewed_posts = get_posts( $args );
}
foreach( $most_viewed_posts as $post ) : 
    //blahblah
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The problem is that the third loop doesnt show the right posts, as if it doesnt recognize the post meta, however if i use query_posts then it works!

> views v_sortby, v_orderby

Any help is appreciated, I am quite new to this.

**Update**
According to similar question asked on this [site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6796/how-to-change-loop-to-order-posts-by-views-using-wp-postviews-plugin). below is another way of achieving it using query_posts with meta keys. I guess there is a better way of rewriting the code to use meta keys + wp_query or get_posts someone care to? I am very new to this, looks too chunky? :S

```
<?php $posts_per_page = get_query_var('posts_per_page'); ?>
<?php $paged = intval(get_query_var('paged')); ?>
<?php $paged = ($paged) ? $paged : 1; ?>
<?php $args = array(
'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
'paged' => $paged,
'more' => $more = 0,
'meta_key' => 'views',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'DESC',
); ?>
<?php query_posts($args); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post() ;?>
<div <?php post_class() ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
```

Comment: Read following article for general info why you shouldn't use `query_posts` ever:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Comment: what plugin is used for the 'most viewed'? have you tried to re-write the loops or at least the third loop with `WP_Query()`?

Comment: It's WP-Views by Lester Chan http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postviews/

Comment: Yeah I've tried but probably I am missing something. normally when I want to display most viewed posts I use `(http://mydomain.com/?v_sortby=views&v_orderby=desc` and to use them as a secondary loop I can fetch them using the unrecomendable function query_posts() like `query_posts(array('v_sortby' => 'views', 'v_orderby' => 'DESC', 'showposts' => 10, 'cat'=>$cat));` and it works but people say not to use query_posts() so I wanted to try get_posts() or wp_query() but i am having trouble.

Comment: Use `new WP_Query()` for all three loops. After each loop, call [**`wp_reset_postdata()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata).

Comment: Hi chip, one more question, now is all working, but I forgot to mention to in a few articles that I read, authors kept on mentioning that get_posts() is better performance wise since it doesnt fetch all the data and information that wp_query fetches? I am not using all the information that is gathered by wp_query, how true is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to tips given by the commentators I was able to achieve this :)

```
    <?php 
if ( is_front_age() ){
                    $most_viewed_posts = new WP_Query( array('v_sortby' => 'views', 'v_orderby' => 'DESC', 'showposts' => 10, 'cat'=> 3) );
                    }
                    while ( $most_viewed_posts->have_posts() ) : $most_viewed_posts->the_post(); ?>

//post structure

 <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```